# WebStorm + CodeKit?

Tags: ide, webstorm, codekit

Does anyone know how to setup [WebStorm](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jetbrains.com%2Fwebstorm%2F&ei=juf8U8uEIqXMsQSB7YDwCA&usg=AFQjCNHMZG4Ee6khYI6OsfB2wUB3sSRYMA) to work with [CodeKit](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fincident57.com%2Fcodekit%2F&ei=oef8U7nHFdPfsASsu4KIDg&usg=AFQjCNGfsPne4-ZAXq_N7LPGl9Zzccu_XQ) on a mac?

The ultimate goal is to get codekit to run and compile the my scss when a file is saved in WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

May be I have miss understood your question but, webstorm can compile your scss files automatically whenever you change them. Why do you need codekit to run?

Comment: Webstorm's website says it does not compile files for you it only let's you choose a compiler.

Comment: if you save a scss file webstorm can automatically produce css file. check this link please: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html#d128637e458

Comment: "WebStorm supports integration with transpiler tools that translate Sass, Less, and SCSS code into CSS." Integration... meaning you still need to have a compiler in place. In this case the compiler I was using was codekit.

Comment: @gdaniel, yes you are right. You also setup a File Watcher from settings. CodeKit is not in the list so you should select custom. But I think you already figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer. From my initial test, I had both CodeKit and Webstorm open together. When I had Webstorm compile the SCSS it produced the map file which helps debug the SCSS files and changed the scss in CodeKit. Whereas codekit does not produce the map but produces a config file. I guess that it depends on who else needs to work with your code.